# Creating a QGIS Plugin with Plugin Builder - recipe from QGIS Python Programming Cookbook by Joel Lawhead - QGIS 2.18

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have a trouble with recipe "Creating a QGIS Plugin" from QGIS Python Cookbook by Joel Lawhead. I use QGIS 2.18, Plugin Builder and OSGeo4W Shell.
I can't walk through this step:

> Compile the *ui* file using the *pyuic4* tool:

```
pyuic4 -o ui_myplugin.py ui_myplugin.ui
```

OSGeo4W Shell displays an error:

> No such file or directory: "ui_myplugin.ui"

What is the cause?

Comment: You've got the output flag (-o) on the input file. Try pyuic4 -o ui_myplugin.ui ui_myplugin.py

Comment: Sorry, I had editing mistake in my question. I corrected them. In OSGeo Shell I wrote "pyuic4 -o ui_myplugin.py ui_myplugin.ui". I'll check your suggestion.

Comment: Are you in the plugin repository when you execute this command? Are the files there? Use 'pwd' command for "print working directory" to check it. You should be in some repository like C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins\nameofyourplugin if you are on Windows.

Comment: Yes, I am in the plugin folder path. There is only one ui file named myplugin_dialog_base.ui. I don't have file named ui_myplugin.ui:/

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue using QGIS 2.18, which was that I did not have a file named 'ui_myplugin.ui'. The solution was to use the 'myplugin_dialog_base.ui' file in place of the 'ui_myplugin.ui'.

So the command is:

```
pyuic4 –o ui_myplugin.py myplugin_dialog_base.ui
```

Additionally, I needed to change another step from the tutorial in order to get my plugin to work. The tutorial says to use:

```
pyrcc4 –o resources_rc.py resources.qrc
```

However, in order for QGIS to load my test plugin without any errors I needed to do:

```
pyrcc4 –o resources.py resources.qrc
```